# MS Excel - Can't color or replace cells by using * character

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel document with numbers in the cells. Additionally, some cells show either * or ** after the number (representing significance of correlation).

When I try to color those cells with conditional formatting, Excel colors all the cells. Also, when I try to replace * with another char, it replaces all of the letters in the document. So I'm thinking Excel understands * as "all characters in the document". How do I go around this?

Comment: Yes, excel and many other programming languages use * to represent a "wild card" for partial matches.  Try prefexing your search for * with ~*

Comment: @ForwardEd, consider expanding that into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around the problem of `*` being a wildcard by making your own conditional formatting rule.

The function `=FIND()` does not allow wildcards. So if you make a condition for `A1` looking like this: `=FIND("*",A1)` and then apply it to all the cells you want to check.
You can compound this with a `=FIND("**",A1)` if you want to format those differently.

[image]

Comment: Nevermind, the comment solution is far easier...